# Iterate through python list and extract all matching strings found in a second list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I would like to go through each element in my 'match' list and extract all the strings where this key word appears - it can be upper or lower case:

Please could someone let me know where I am going wrong?

My code that I have tried is:

```
match=['FUN','HAPPY','FLORAL', 'alpha','12133','water12']
data=['the fun we are', 'hello there', 'Happy today is the case','112133 is it', 'FLORAL is my fave']

lst=[]
for i in match:
    for j in data:
        if i.lower() in j.lower():
            lst.append(j)
    else:
        lst.append('not found')
```

desired output:

```
lst=['the fun we are','Happy today is the case','112133 is it' ,'FLORAL is my fave']
```

Thank you

Comment: You can apply [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with generator. `any(m.lower() in i.lower() for m in match)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to archive your desired result:

```
>>> match=['FUN','HAPPY','FLORAL', 'alpha','12133','water12']
>>> data=['the fun we are', 'hello there', 'Happy today is the case','112133 is it', 'FLORAL is my fave']
>>> lst = [sentence for sentence in data if any(word.lower() in sentence.lower() for word in match)]
>>> lst
['the fun we are', 'Happy today is the case', '112133 is it', 'FLORAL is my fave']
```

If you remove the else part in your code, the `not found` entries will no be added and you can archive the same result (in a different order if this is important):

```
>>> lst=[]
>>> for i in match:
...     for j in data:
...         if i.lower() in j.lower():
...             lst.append(j)
...
>>> lst
['the fun we are', 'Happy today is the case', 'FLORAL is my fave', '112133 is it']
```

Comment: Thank you! However, in my real code I get the error `'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`. any ideas why this could be? my data is a column from a dataframe which I convert into a list

Comment: It seems that one of your list does not only consists of of words (strings), but also of numbers (floats). To handle this case, you can convert all values to strings by calling the `str` function. Just exchange `word.lower()` to `str(word).lower()` and `sentence.lower()` to `str(sentence).lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Prior answer from [Querenker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4113721/querenker) summed up the approaches nicely. However, if you want to preserve an additional feature (which it seems you intended to include) whereby `"not found"` is returned when there is no agreement between the lists, here is an alternative:

```
lst=[]
for i in match:
    for j in data:
        if i.lower() in j.lower():
            lst.append(j)
else:
    if lst == []:
        print('not found')
```